# Customized alert box or default alert box inside service in Android

Tags: android, service, android-alertdialog

I have created a service that keeps checking my databsae (remote) for results. If the results are found I want a dialog box that shows - Results found please click OK to see in detail - Is this possible inside service class.

After intense search for alert box in service I couldn't find much on google. Hence posting a question.

Comment: The alert is going to be shown from service.... so I will choose Notification instead of using alert.

Comment: I prefer alert box reason because I miss the notification sometimes...

Comment: :D nice choice.. good to know.

Comment: A service doing background work independent from the UI should not be displaying dialogs of any form. You have no idea what the user is doing at that moment, and interrupting them with a modal UI will cause irritation at best and casualties at worst (e.g., you interrupting their use of the device for car navigation). Please have the service either tell a foreground activity to do something, or display a `Notification` if there you are not in the foreground.